# How to calculate throughput in Kpps?

Tags: router, firewall, bandwidth, throughput

I'm going to buy a firewall.For the first step i must calculate my network throughput in Kpps.
I'm using Mikrotik routerOs. Mikrotik has bandwidth test that it shows traffic in Kbps.
How do I find my network throughput in Kpps?

Answer (score 4):

The bandwidth test will not help you properly determine your firewall needs, as it is only testing how much available bandwidth you have.

Graphing either through RouterOS or through a third party system should be used to measure the actual amount of traffic being used over time. When purchasing a firewall you will want to determine all the metrics in making your decision, and how your use of features will change your baseline.

Graphing can be setup by navigating to your device in your web browser /graphs

Packets per seconds is displayed in RouterOS as (P/s). This can also be viewed on a live basis under "interfaces".

http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:Tools/Graphing